# How to set the color of mat-form-field-appearance-outline for invalid state Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have set the outline color on hover successfully. But when I try to set outline color for hover in invalid state it does not work. My code is given below:

```
 &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
               //It works it set the color to blue
                color: blue;
                
                //It does not work
                &.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid {
                        color: red;
                }
            }
```

The color for invalid state &.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid is not working. Please help me. If someone knows how to solve it the please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follow:

```
&.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
   color: blue;    
}

&.error {          
   &.mat-form-field-appearance-outline:not(.mat-form-field-disabled) .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
      color: red;
   }
}
```